# Check any one match in array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like below.

```
(
[TestData1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SKU] => A01
                [SKUType] => Test
                [State] => Yes

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
               [SKU] => A02
               [SKUType] => Test
               [State] => Yes

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [SKU] => A01
               [SKUType] => Test
               [State] => Yes

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
               [SKU] => A03
               [SKUType] => Test
               [State] => Yes

            )

    )

[TestData2] => Array
    (
    )

[TestData3] => Array
    (
    )

 )
```

I need to check if the given SKU is exist or not in the TestData1 array.

If exist need to check the State value that should be Yes.

Example given sku is

```
   $skutotest = 'A01';
```

How to find if the value present in the above array using PHP.

Right now i tried like below.

```
$Details = result_array; // here reading array data from api
$parent_sku = A01;
$Results = $Details['$TestData1'];
    foreach($Results as $res){
        $sku= $res['SKU'];
        $state = $res['State'];
        if($sku== $parent_sku && $state == "Yes"){
            return true;
            break;
        }else{
            return false;
         }
    }
```

Once i found the match, need to stop executing and return true, is the above code correct?

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: try something like: `array_search(array_column($arr, "SKU"), 'A01')`

Comment: @dWinder, I need to check state field also.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: So simple `foreach` with `if` statement should do it

Comment: @jeroen, yes i am updating my code

Comment: @jeroen, I have updated my code, pls share your ideas

Comment: with [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) you can get the key so you can acces to the array $TestData1[$key]['State']

Comment: @Sfili_81, Am i using correctly, can u tell is that correct?

Comment: Some typo i think,must be $Details = "result"; $parent_sku = "A01";$Results = $Details['$TestData1'];?

Comment: @Sfili_81, yes updated my question , pls check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one liner,

```
$exists = false;
$key    = "TestData1";
$skutotest    = "A01";
if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) { // for check if key exists
    return ($arr[$key][array_search($skutotest, array_column($arr[$key], 'SKU'))]['State'] == 'Yes');
}
```

[array_search](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37881c3a21e087ed5fedb1c1379d601e90383d42).

**EDIT**

Proper solution for your problem,

```
$exists = false;
$key    = "TestData1";
$val    = "A01";
if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
    array_walk($arr[$key], function ($item) use ($val, &$exists) {
        if ($item['SKU'] == $val && $item['State'] == 'Yes') {
            $exists = true;
            return;
        }
    });
}
return ($exists);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae25aa6386ef9a87390a27de35c0686bf67d518c)

Comment: what is $key in the above code, not cleared, can u pls update little bit clear

Comment: The value is assigned in my code right, as you mentioned to check for `TestData1`, so hardcoded that, do you need it dynamic? If yes, then replace that with input value of yours.

Comment: Notice that if "SKU" if not uniqe `array_search` will return only first result so it may fail

Comment: Thanks mate, then I will make changes as per that.

Comment: TestData1 near it remove that dollar

Answer (score 0):

Following function has been used in the solution :

> **[array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) - Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values**
>
> **[array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) - Return the values from a single column in the input array**
>
> **[array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) - Checks if the given key or index exists in the array**

```
$skuToSearch  = 'A01';
$parentKey    = 'TestData1';
$res = array_combine(
        array_column($arr[$parentKey] , 'SKU'), 
        array_column($arr[$parentKey] , 'State')
     );
$found = (array_key_exists($skuToSearch, $res)  && $res[$skuToSearch] == 'Yes') ? true : false;
```

**Explanation:**

- *variable `$skuToSearch`, put the SKU which you want to search.*
- *variable `$parentKey` hold the `key` of the parent subarray.*
- *`array_column($arr[$parentKey] , 'SKU')` will return an array with `SKU's`*
- *`array_column($arr[$parentKey] , 'State')` will return an array with `States`*
- *Variable `$found` will return `true` OR `false`, if the `SKU` found and have `state` values `Yes`*